# python 3 regex: match a character exactly once

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

a sentence needs to contain 1 or more instances of 'a', exactly 1 instance of 'b' and 0 or more instances of 'c'
my expression is    `a+bc*`
it works for strings like 'abc' 'ab' 'aabcc' which is all fine but it also works when i have multiple b's like 'abbc' which it shouldn't. How do i get it to work when theres only 1 'b'

Here is my full code

```
import re
qq = re.compile('a+bc*')
if qq.match('abb') is not None:
    print("True")
else:
    print('False')
```

which should produce False

Comment: What is your desired output from your logic? A `True` or `False` depending on your criteria? Since you have some code, sharing it with us will help us correct your problem.

Comment: What code did you use to check this? Please post the code as well

Comment: Take a look at this [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=a%2Bbc*&test_string=abbc&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) it shouldn't capture all of `'abbc'`

Comment: `a+bc*` matches `abb` because there is one `a` followed by one `b`.  So it has matched after the second character.  The second `b` is ignored.

Comment: The `re.match` method checks only the beginning of the string. To describe all the string until the end you have to add `$` in your pattern.

Comment: yeah even regex101 does that but if you run the code above in a compiler it will return True

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that worked! thanks sir

Comment: You can also use the `re.fullmatch` method (since the 3.4 version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `qq=re.compile(r'^a+bc*$')`. The `^` means match at start and `$` means match at the end.

You want to match the pattern to the full string and not a part of it. That is why you need the `^` and `$` in this case

Comment: in regex, `^` means the start of the string, and `$` means the end